# Interpret and Plot FFT Results

Tags: c#, math, signal-processing, fft

I am trying to do a FFT of some Signals I get from a Vibration Sensor. My Problem is my output is wrong or maybe my interpretation of the output is wrong.

I am using the FFT algorithm of Paul Bourke:

```
public static void FFT(short dir, int m, double[] x, double[] y) 
{ 
    int n, i, i1, j, k, i2, l, l1, l2; 
    double c1, c2, tx, ty, t1, t2, u1, u2, z; 

    // Calculate the number of points 

    n = 1; 

    for (i = 0; i < m; i++) 
        n *= 2; 

    // Do the bit reversal 

    i2 = n >> 1; 
    j = 0; 
    for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) 
    { 
        if (i < j) 
        { 
            tx = x[i]; 
            ty = y[i]; 
            x[i] = x[j]; 
            y[i] = y[j]; 
            x[j] = tx; 
            y[j] = ty; 
        } 
        k = i2; 

        while (k <= j) 
        { 
            j -= k; 
            k >>= 1; 
        } 

        j += k; 
    } 

    // Compute the FFT 

    c1 = -1.0; 
    c2 = 0.0; 
    l2 = 1; 

    for (l = 0; l < m; l++) 
    { 
        l1 = l2; 
        l2 <<= 1; 
        u1 = 1.0; 
        u2 = 0.0; 

        for (j = 0; j < l1; j++) 
        { 
            for (i = j; i < n; i += l2) 
            { 
                i1 = i + l1; 
                t1 = u1 * x[i1] - u2 * y[i1]; 
                t2 = u1 * y[i1] + u2 * x[i1]; 
                x[i1] = x[i] - t1; 
                y[i1] = y[i] - t2; 
                x[i] += t1; 
                y[i] += t2; 
            } 

            z = u1 * c1 - u2 * c2; 
            u2 = u1 * c2 + u2 * c1; 
            u1 = z; 
        } 

        c2 = Math.Sqrt((1.0 - c1) / 2.0); 

        if (dir == 1) 
            c2 = -c2; 

        c1 = Math.Sqrt((1.0 + c1) / 2.0); 
    } 

    // Scaling for forward transform 

    if (dir == 1) 
    { 
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) 
        { 
            x[i] /= n; 
            y[i] /= n; 
        } 
    } 
}
```

To Plot the `Frequenzy/Amplitude Graph` I calculate a Frequenzy and Amplitude array out of the Im- and Re-Parts:

```
public double[] Frequency(Vector2XYArray input, float intervall)//FrequenzArray of the Inputs
{ 
    int i = 0; //Position in array
    double Fs = 1 / intervall; //sampling rate in Hz
    int size = input.Count; //size of the  input
    double[] output = new double[size];
    foreach(var line in input)
    {
        double frequenzy = i * Fs / size; 
        //double frequenzy = i * Fs / (size / 2 - 1);
        output[i] = frequenzy;
        i++;
    }
    return output;
}

public double[] Magnitude(Vector2XYArray input) // Calculate Magnitude
{
    double[] output = new double[input.Count];
    int i = 0;//orginal 0
    foreach (var line in input)
    {
        output[i] = Math.Sqrt(line.X * line.X + line.Y * line.Y);
        i++;
    }       
    return output;
}
```

For example, i have calculated the FFT of a sinus wave. Here is the Input:

[image]

and the Output:

[image]

and this is what I have expected:

[image: Something like this].
Here is the input data:

```
0 0
0.03142 0.03141
0.06283 0.06279
0.09425 0.09411
0.12566 0.12533
0.15708 0.15643
0.1885 0.18738
0.21991 0.21814
0.25133 0.24869
0.28274 0.27899
0.31416 0.30902
0.34558 0.33874
0.37699 0.36812
0.40841 0.39715
0.43982 0.42578
0.47124 0.45399
0.50265 0.48175
0.53407 0.50904
0.56549 0.53583
0.5969 0.56208
0.62832 0.58779
0.65973 0.61291
0.69115 0.63742
0.72257 0.66131
0.75398 0.68455
0.7854 0.70711
0.81681 0.72897
0.84823 0.75011
0.87965 0.77051
0.91106 0.79016
0.94248 0.80902
0.97389 0.82708
1.00531 0.84433
1.03673 0.86074
1.06814 0.87631
1.09956 0.89101
1.13097 0.90483
1.16239 0.91775
1.19381 0.92978
1.22522 0.94088
1.25664 0.95106
1.28805 0.96029
1.31947 0.96858
1.35088 0.97592
1.3823 0.98229
1.41372 0.98769
1.44513 0.99211
1.47655 0.99556
1.50796 0.99803
1.53938 0.99951
1.5708 1
1.60221 0.99951
1.63363   0.99803
1.66504   0.99556
1.69646   0.99211
1.72788   0.98769
1.75929   0.98229
1.79071   0.97592
1.82212   0.96858
1.85354   0.96029
1.88496   0.95106
1.91637   0.94088
1.94779   0.92978
1.9792   0.91775
2.01062   0.90483
2.04204   0.89101
2.07345   0.87631
2.10487   0.86074
2.13628   0.84433
2.1677   0.82708
2.19911  0.80902
2.23053  0.79016
2.26195   0.77051
2.29336   0.75011
2.32478   0.72897
2.35619   0.70711
2.38761   0.68455
2.41903   0.66131
2.45044   0.63742
2.48186   0.61291
2.51327   0.58779
2.54469   0.56208
2.57611   0.53583
2.60752   0.50904
2.63894   0.48175
2.67035   0.45399
2.70177   0.42578
2.73319   0.39715
2.7646   0.36812
2.79602   0.33874
2.82743   0.30902
2.85885   0.27899
2.89027   0.24869
2.92168   0.21814
2.9531   0.18738
2.98451   0.15643
3.01593   0.12533
3.04734   0.09411
3.07876   0.06279
3.11018   0.03141
3.14159   0
3.17301   -0.03141
3.20442   -0.06279
3.23584   -0.09411
3.26726   -0.12533
3.29867   -0.15643
3.33009   -0.18738
3.3615   -0.21814
3.39292   -0.24869
3.42434   -0.27899
3.45575   -0.30902
3.48717   -0.33874
3.51858   -0.36812
3.55   -0.39715
3.58142   -0.42578
3.61283   -0.45399
3.64425   -0.48175
3.67566   -0.50904
3.70708   -0.53583
3.7385   -0.56208
3.76991   -0.58779
3.80133   -0.61291
3.83274   -0.63742
3.86416   -0.66131
3.89557   -0.68455
3.92699   -0.70711
3.95841   -0.72897
3.98982   -0.75011
4.02124   -0.77051
4.05265   -0.79016
4.08407   -0.80902
4.11549   -0.82708
4.1469   -0.84433
4.17832   -0.86074
4.20973   -0.87631
4.24115   -0.89101
4.27257   -0.90483
4.30398   -0.91775
4.3354   -0.92978
4.36681   -0.94088
4.39823   -0.95106
4.42965   -0.96029
4.46106   -0.96858
4.49248   -0.97592
4.52389   -0.98229
4.55531   -0.98769
4.58673   -0.99211
4.61814   -0.99556
4.64956   -0.99803
4.68097   -0.99951
4.71239   -1
4.7438   -0.99951
4.77522   -0.99803
4.80664   -0.99556
4.83805   -0.99211
4.86947   -0.98769
4.90088   -0.98229
4.9323   -0.97592
4.96372   -0.96858
4.99513   -0.96029
5.02655   -0.95106
5.05796   -0.94088
5.08938   -0.92978
5.1208   -0.91775
5.15221   -0.90483
5.18363   -0.89101
5.21504   -0.87631
5.24646   -0.86074
5.27788   -0.84433
5.30929   -0.82708
5.34071   -0.80902
5.37212   -0.79016
5.40354   -0.77051
5.43496   -0.75011
5.46637   -0.72897
5.49779   -0.70711
5.5292   -0.68455
5.56062   -0.66131
5.59203   -0.63742
5.62345   -0.61291
5.65487   -0.58779
5.68628   -0.56208
5.7177   -0.53583
5.74911   -0.50904
5.78053   -0.48175
5.81195   -0.45399
5.84336   -0.42578
5.87478   -0.39715
5.90619   -0.36812
5.93761   -0.33874
5.96903   -0.30902
6.00044   -0.27899
6.03186   -0.24869
6.06327   -0.21814
6.09469   -0.18738
6.12611   -0.15643
6.15752   -0.12533
6.18894   -0.09411
6.22035   -0.06279
6.25177   -0.03141
6.28319   0
```

And here the output of my FFt with re- and im-part:

```
[0]     {[ X      64.500000000000  Y       0.404150873423 ]}
[1]     {[ X      -0.278555512428  Y      20.092735290527 ]}
[2]     {[ X      -0.427216023207  Y      10.135166168213 ]}
[3]     {[ X      -0.454415380955  Y       6.762391567230 ]}
[4]     {[ X      -0.466557115316  Y       5.069226741791 ]}
[5]     {[ X      -0.473544538021  Y       4.050390243530 ]}
[6]     {[ X      -0.478114247322  Y       3.369287729263 ]}
[7]     {[ X      -0.481347471476  Y       2.881366968155 ]}
[8]     {[ X      -0.483760744333  Y       2.514262914658 ]}
[9]     {[ X      -0.485634654760  Y       2.227739095688 ]}
[10]    {[ X      -0.487134367228  Y       1.997638821602 ]}
[11]    {[ X      -0.488363116980  Y       1.808581709862 ]}
[12]    {[ X      -0.489389568567  Y       1.650311112404 ]}
[13]    {[ X      -0.490261167288  Y       1.515723109245 ]}
[14]    {[ X      -0.491011261940  Y       1.399742126465 ]}
[15]    {[ X      -0.491664320230  Y       1.298645377159 ]}
[16]    {[ X      -0.492238879204  Y       1.209639668465 ]}
[17]    {[ X      -0.492749184370  Y       1.130587935448 ]}
[18]    {[ X      -0.493205547333  Y       1.059828639030 ]}
[19]    {[ X      -0.493616372347  Y       0.996048748493 ]}
[20]    {[ X      -0.493989378214  Y       0.938197791576 ]}
[21]    {[ X      -0.494329094887  Y       0.885425508022 ]}
[22]    {[ X      -0.494640737772  Y       0.837034225464 ]}
[23]    {[ X      -0.494927674532  Y       0.792449653149 ]}
[24]    {[ X      -0.495193183422  Y       0.751191437244 ]}
[25]    {[ X      -0.495440214872  Y       0.712855517864 ]}
[26]    {[ X      -0.495669990778  Y       0.677102446556 ]}
[27]    {[ X      -0.495885282755  Y       0.643638551235 ]}
[28]    {[ X      -0.496086686850  Y       0.612215101719 ]}
[29]    {[ X      -0.496277689934  Y       0.582615792751 ]}
[30]    {[ X      -0.496457248926  Y       0.554655015469 ]}
[31]    {[ X      -0.496627360582  Y       0.528167366982 ]}
[32]    {[ X      -0.496789306402  Y       0.503011226654 ]}
[33]    {[ X      -0.496942907572  Y       0.479060232639 ]}
[34]    {[ X      -0.497089982033  Y       0.456202059984 ]}
[35]    {[ X      -0.497230142355  Y       0.434339284897 ]}
[36]    {[ X      -0.497365087271  Y       0.413383096457 ]}
[37]    {[ X      -0.497494697571  Y       0.393253803253 ]}
[38]    {[ X      -0.497618973255  Y       0.373881310225 ]}
[39]    {[ X      -0.497739076614  Y       0.355201095343 ]}
[40]    {[ X      -0.497855097055  Y       0.337155520916 ]}
[41]    {[ X      -0.497966945171  Y       0.319692194462 ]}
[42]    {[ X      -0.498075932264  Y       0.302763164043 ]}
[43]    {[ X      -0.498181402683  Y       0.286324679852 ]}
[44]    {[ X      -0.498284250498  Y       0.270337581635 ]}
[45]    {[ X      -0.498384326696  Y       0.254763960838 ]}
[46]    {[ X      -0.498481482267  Y       0.239570736885 ]}
[47]    {[ X      -0.498577028513  Y       0.224725276232 ]}
[48]    {[ X      -0.498670279980  Y       0.210199967027 ]}
[49]    {[ X      -0.498761832714  Y       0.195966750383 ]}
[50]    {[ X      -0.498851388693  Y       0.182000353932 ]}
[51]    {[ X      -0.498939424753  Y       0.168277233839 ]}
[52]    {[ X      -0.499026447535  Y       0.154774993658 ]}
[53]    {[ X      -0.499111831188  Y       0.141471460462 ]}
[54]    {[ X      -0.499196022749  Y       0.128347560763 ]}
[55]    {[ X      -0.499279111624  Y       0.115384347737 ]}
[56]    {[ X      -0.499361395836  Y       0.102562248707 ]}
[57]    {[ X      -0.499442815781  Y       0.089865408838 ]}
[58]    {[ X      -0.499524056911  Y       0.077276006341 ]}
[59]    {[ X      -0.499603927135  Y       0.064778119326 ]}
[60]    {[ X      -0.499683767557  Y       0.052354805171 ]}
[61]    {[ X      -0.499763309956  Y       0.039992045611 ]}
[62]    {[ X      -0.499842256308  Y       0.027673484758 ]}
[63]    {[ X      -0.499921083450  Y       0.015384667553 ]}
[64]    {[ X      -0.500000000000  Y       0.003110077232 ]}
[65]    {[ X      -0.500078916550  Y      -0.009163955227 ]}
[66]    {[ X      -0.500157713890  Y      -0.021453363821 ]}
[67]    {[ X      -0.500236690044  Y      -0.033772386611 ]}
[68]    {[ X      -0.500316202641  Y      -0.046136599034 ]}
[69]    {[ X      -0.500396072865  Y      -0.058560118079 ]}
[70]    {[ X      -0.500475943089  Y      -0.071059986949 ]}
[71]    {[ X      -0.500557184219  Y      -0.083651058376 ]}
[72]    {[ X      -0.500638604164  Y      -0.096350118518 ]}
[73]    {[ X      -0.500720918179  Y      -0.109173156321 ]}
[74]    {[ X      -0.500803947449  Y      -0.122139394283 ]}
[75]    {[ X      -0.500888168812  Y      -0.135265812278 ]}
[76]    {[ X      -0.500973582268  Y      -0.148571684957 ]}
[77]    {[ X      -0.501060605049  Y      -0.162078142166 ]}
[78]    {[ X      -0.501148641109  Y      -0.175805360079 ]}
[79]    {[ X      -0.501238167286  Y      -0.189775809646 ]}
[80]    {[ X      -0.501329720020  Y      -0.204013600945 ]}
[81]    {[ X      -0.501422941685  Y      -0.218544244766 ]}
[82]    {[ X      -0.501518487930  Y      -0.233394041657 ]}
[83]    {[ X      -0.501615643501  Y      -0.248593732715 ]}
[84]    {[ X      -0.501715779305  Y      -0.264173567295 ]}
[85]    {[ X      -0.501818597317  Y      -0.280168324709 ]}
[86]    {[ X      -0.501924037933  Y      -0.296613782644 ]}
[87]    {[ X      -0.502033054829  Y      -0.313550800085 ]}
[88]    {[ X      -0.502144873142  Y      -0.331023126841 ]}
[89]    {[ X      -0.502260923386  Y      -0.349078357220 ]}
[90]    {[ X      -0.502381026745  Y      -0.367769241333 ]}
[91]    {[ X      -0.502505302429  Y      -0.387153834105 ]}
[92]    {[ X      -0.502634882927  Y      -0.407295674086 ]}
[93]    {[ X      -0.502769887447  Y      -0.428266674280 ]}
[94]    {[ X      -0.502910017967  Y      -0.450145125389 ]}
[95]    {[ X      -0.503057062626  Y      -0.473018914461 ]}
[96]    {[ X      -0.503210723400  Y      -0.496988743544 ]}
[97]    {[ X      -0.503372609615  Y      -0.522165477276 ]}
[98]    {[ X      -0.503542780876  Y      -0.548675000668 ]}
[99]    {[ X      -0.503722310066  Y      -0.576662123203 ]}
[100]   {[ X      -0.503913283348  Y      -0.606288433075 ]}
[101]   {[ X      -0.504114747047  Y      -0.637743055820 ]}
[102]   {[ X      -0.504329979420  Y      -0.671241462231 ]}
[103]   {[ X      -0.504559814930  Y      -0.707035362720 ]}
[104]   {[ X      -0.504806816578  Y      -0.745414316654 ]}
[105]   {[ X      -0.505072295666  Y      -0.786722958088 ]}
[106]   {[ X      -0.505359232426  Y      -0.831364929676 ]}
[107]   {[ X      -0.505670905113  Y      -0.879821360111 ]}
[108]   {[ X      -0.506010591984  Y      -0.932670652866 ]}
[109]   {[ X      -0.506383597851  Y      -0.990610063076 ]}
[110]   {[ X      -0.506794452667  Y      -1.054493665695 ]}
[111]   {[ X      -0.507250845432  Y      -1.125375986099 ]}
[112]   {[ X      -0.507761120796  Y      -1.204573869705 ]}
[113]   {[ X      -0.508335649967  Y      -1.293757200241 ]}
[114]   {[ X      -0.508988738060  Y      -1.395070672035 ]}
[115]   {[ X      -0.509738802910  Y      -1.511319994926 ]}
[116]   {[ X      -0.510610461235  Y      -1.646247148514 ]}
[117]   {[ X      -0.511636853218  Y      -1.804953932762 ]}
[118]   {[ X      -0.512865602970  Y      -1.994584918022 ]}
[119]   {[ X      -0.514365315437  Y      -2.225463151932 ]}
[120]   {[ X      -0.516239285469  Y      -2.513076543808 ]}
[121]   {[ X      -0.518652498722  Y      -2.881775140762 ]}
[122]   {[ X      -0.521885752678  Y      -3.372164726257 ]}
[123]   {[ X      -0.526455461979  Y      -4.057395458221 ]}
[124]   {[ X      -0.533442914486  Y      -5.083943843842 ]}
[125]   {[ X      -0.545584619045  Y      -6.794277667999 ]}
[126]   {[ X      -0.572783946991  Y     -10.220301628113 ]}
[127]   {[ X      -0.721444487572  Y     -20.642747879028 ]}
[128]   {[ X     129.000000000000  Y      -0.790160000324 ]}
[129]   {[ X     130.000000000000  Y      -0.809019982815 ]}
[130]   {[ X     131.000000000000  Y      -0.827080011368 ]}
[131]   {[ X     132.000000000000  Y      -0.844330012798 ]}
[132]   {[ X     133.000000000000  Y      -0.860740005970 ]}
[133]   {[ X     134.000000000000  Y      -0.876309990883 ]}
[134]   {[ X     135.000000000000  Y      -0.891009986401 ]}
[135]   {[ X     136.000000000000  Y      -0.904829978943 ]}
[136]   {[ X     137.000000000000  Y      -0.917750000954 ]}
[137]   {[ X     138.000000000000  Y      -0.929780006409 ]}
[138]   {[ X     139.000000000000  Y      -0.940880000591 ]}
[139]   {[ X     140.000000000000  Y      -0.951059997082 ]}
[140]   {[ X     141.000000000000  Y      -0.960290014744 ]}
[141]   {[ X     142.000000000000  Y      -0.968580007553 ]}
[142]   {[ X     143.000000000000  Y      -0.975920021534 ]}
[143]   {[ X     144.000000000000  Y      -0.982290029526 ]}
[144]   {[ X     145.000000000000  Y      -0.987689971924 ]}
[145]   {[ X     146.000000000000  Y      -0.992110013962 ]}
[146]   {[ X     147.000000000000  Y      -0.995559990406 ]}
[147]   {[ X     148.000000000000  Y      -0.998030006886 ]}
[148]   {[ X     149.000000000000  Y      -0.999509990215 ]}
[149]   {[ X     150.000000000000  Y      -1.000000000000 ]}
[150]   {[ X     151.000000000000  Y      -0.999509990215 ]}
[151]   {[ X     152.000000000000  Y      -0.998030006886 ]}
[152]   {[ X     153.000000000000  Y      -0.995559990406 ]}
[153]   {[ X     154.000000000000  Y      -0.992110013962 ]}
[154]   {[ X     155.000000000000  Y      -0.987689971924 ]}
[155]   {[ X     156.000000000000  Y      -0.982290029526 ]}
[156]   {[ X     157.000000000000  Y      -0.975920021534 ]}
[157]   {[ X     158.000000000000  Y      -0.968580007553 ]}
[158]   {[ X     159.000000000000  Y      -0.960290014744 ]}
[159]   {[ X     160.000000000000  Y      -0.951059997082 ]}
[160]   {[ X     161.000000000000  Y      -0.940880000591 ]}
[161]   {[ X     162.000000000000  Y      -0.929780006409 ]}
[162]   {[ X     163.000000000000  Y      -0.917750000954 ]}
[163]   {[ X     164.000000000000  Y      -0.904829978943 ]}
[164]   {[ X     165.000000000000  Y      -0.891009986401 ]}
[165]   {[ X     166.000000000000  Y      -0.876309990883 ]}
[166]   {[ X     167.000000000000  Y      -0.860740005970 ]}
[167]   {[ X     168.000000000000  Y      -0.844330012798 ]}
[168]   {[ X     169.000000000000  Y      -0.827080011368 ]}
[169]   {[ X     170.000000000000  Y      -0.809019982815 ]}
[170]   {[ X     171.000000000000  Y      -0.790160000324 ]}
[171]   {[ X     172.000000000000  Y      -0.770510017872 ]}
[172]   {[ X     173.000000000000  Y      -0.750109970570 ]}
[173]   {[ X     174.000000000000  Y      -0.728969991207 ]}
[174]   {[ X     175.000000000000  Y      -0.707109987736 ]}
[175]   {[ X     176.000000000000  Y      -0.684549987316 ]}
[176]   {[ X     177.000000000000  Y      -0.661310017109 ]}
[177]   {[ X     178.000000000000  Y      -0.637419998646 ]}
[178]   {[ X     179.000000000000  Y      -0.612909972668 ]}
[179]   {[ X     180.000000000000  Y      -0.587790012360 ]}
[180]   {[ X     181.000000000000  Y      -0.562080025673 ]}
[181]   {[ X     182.000000000000  Y      -0.535830020905 ]}
[182]   {[ X     183.000000000000  Y      -0.509039998055 ]}
[183]   {[ X     184.000000000000  Y      -0.481750011444 ]}
[184]   {[ X     185.000000000000  Y      -0.453990012407 ]}
[185]   {[ X     186.000000000000  Y      -0.425779998302 ]}
[186]   {[ X     187.000000000000  Y      -0.397150009871 ]}
[187]   {[ X     188.000000000000  Y      -0.368120014668 ]}
[188]   {[ X     189.000000000000  Y      -0.338739991188 ]}
[189]   {[ X     190.000000000000  Y      -0.309020012617 ]}
[190]   {[ X     191.000000000000  Y      -0.278990000486 ]}
[191]   {[ X     192.000000000000  Y      -0.248689994216 ]}
[192]   {[ X     193.000000000000  Y      -0.218140006065 ]}
[193]   {[ X     194.000000000000  Y      -0.187380000949 ]}
[194]   {[ X     195.000000000000  Y      -0.156430006027 ]}
[195]   {[ X     196.000000000000  Y      -0.125330001116 ]}
[196]   {[ X     197.000000000000  Y      -0.094109997153 ]}
[197]   {[ X     198.000000000000  Y      -0.062789998949 ]}
[198]   {[ X     199.000000000000  Y      -0.031410001218 ]}
[199]   {[ X     200.000000000000  Y       0.000000000000 ]}
```

The x-value in my output is unnormal high and i don´t know why, but I am shure my FFt works right...

And here with 10kHz and 11 Periods: Input:

[image]

Output:

[image]

The final project should make a FFT from a input with 1792000 datasets. I already got the data and know how the output from the final signal should look like, but my calculated output is not even close.
Here u can see the Final Input:

[image] and

my Output:

[image]  with 51kHz. And this:

[image]

is how it should look like.

What  have I done wrong?

I hope you can help me and thanks for your attention.

Comment: “The output is wrong” is not very helpful - please give more information about the time domain signal, the spectrum you expect, and the spectrum you observe, ideally with plots.

Comment: @PaulR I have added the input and output of a simple sinus wave. Also i have testet my fftt algorithm with this litle test : http://www.sccon.ca/sccon/fft/fft3.htm and it looks like my fft works fine, so there must be a mistake in my interpretation.

Comment: What is the size of the input (no of points) and what is the sample rate (in Hz) ? And how much of your sine wave are you actually sampling ?

Comment: @PaulR  the inpute has a size of 201 data sets, the sample rate is 32Hz (31.826) and I sample just 1 periode (shown in the input-graph).

Comment: Your sinusoidal input has a frequency of ~0.15Hz, so I would expect the output to have a spike in one of the lowest bins (more specifically in bin 1 when `size/Fs ~6.28`).

Comment: Try the same test with a higher frequency, e.g. 10 periods instead of 1.

Comment: @PaulR I added a Graph with 10 Periods and 10KHz. Also I added the final Graph what i get and what it should look like.

Comment: The spectrum for 10 cycle seems looks correct - I think you may just be getting confused about the frequency axis. If you have 10 full cycles in the sampling window then the peak will be in the 10th bin. It also looks like you may have an off-by-one error when you create the input signal, which is resulting in a DC offset (bin 0).

Comment: yes I thought this too, but the output of the final FFT with the huge input is so much different as the one I should get (and I am shure the output I try to get is correct... )

Comment: I will look over the code again but I am pretty shure there is no off-by-one error.

Comment: From the data you show, I'd say Sim91 is mostly right. I think your bin 0 always has a value that is too large. It should be 0 in the case of the two sinusoids, and a lot smaller in the last case. That last case, if bin 0 is smaller, the rest of the bins would be scaled differently, and could potentially look like your expected output.

Comment: @PaulR  I edited my post with the input and output signals of the 1 periode sinus wave... the ouput[0] is much to highin my opinion, but i dont know why.  Yes I think u are right but i don´t know why my value in output[0] is so high

Comment: Output[0] represents the DC (0 Hz) component - try calculating the average of your input samples and see if it's 0. If not then work back from there to see where the problem is.

Comment: @PaulR I calculated the Y input samples and the average ist 0.

Comment: OK - I see one big problem - your data size is 201 but you're using an FFT routine which is radix-2 - you can only process FFT sizes which are powers of 2 with this function. Either: (a) make your data size, say, 256, or (b) pad your data with 0 to make it, say, size 256 or (c) use a different, mixed-radix FFT which supports arbitrary size FFTs.

Comment: @PaulR I shorten the input data, so that only the first 2^n datasets are calculated, means from the 201 inputs only the first 128 inputs are calculated. Or do you think this is not the right way? The output is the same

Comment: As I said above, you can zero pad to 256, or use a mixed radix FFT, or change the input data or sample rate to get a power of 2. The FFT you are currently using probably just truncates to 128 anyway, so you haven’t really changed anything.

Comment: @PaulR ok i will try to implement the Bluestein Algorithm. I hope i can share my results today or tomorrow

Comment: Zero-padding would probably be easier, but it's up to you...

Comment: i will implement both algorithms, the finished tool should be able to compare the different transformations for a later project of myself

Comment: @PaulR i made a remake of my post with new implementation but almost the same problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48638150/fft-bluestein-and-cooley-tukey-unexpected-peak-at-the-begining