# FFT (Bluestein and Cooley-Tukey )... unexpected peak at the begining

Tags: c#, math, graph, fft, dft

some days ago I posted my FFT-Test tool with some problems, so this here is my "remake" poste with almost the same problems, but different code.

Problem:
I´m trying to make a tool to read some sensor values and do the fft of these. I implemented a normal DFT, a FFT(Bluestein) and a FFT(Cooley-Tukey). It all works fine and the inverse transformation shows the input like it should.
The only thing is when i plot the Frequenz/Amplitude graph i have a huge peak at the begining (not only at 0 like the DC (0Hz) component should be!).

For Bluestein and DFT I use the complet input and for Cooley-Tukey I calculate with ZeroPadding or just cut the input to a 2^n length.

For example here is my input, just a simple sinuswave.
Here the output with DFT and Bluetstein(looks the same) and [FFT(ZeroPadding)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8diW.jpg) and one [DFT zoomed in at 0Hz](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ey4k.jpg).
And here is the [ouput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gpZXd.jpg) of the same input with octave, what I expected to get.

Here my Code fore CT-FFT

```
            public static void TransformRadix2(Complex[] vector, bool inverse)
        {
            // Length variables
            int n = vector.Length;
            int levels = 0;  // compute levels = floor(log2(n))
            for (int temp = n; temp > 1; temp >>= 1)
                levels++;
            if (1 << levels != n)
                throw new ArgumentException("Length is not a power of 2");

            // Trigonometric table
            Complex[] expTable = new Complex[n / 2];
            double coef = 2 * Math.PI / n * (inverse ? 1 : -1);
            for (int i = 0; i < n / 2; i++)
                expTable[i] = Complex.Exp(new Complex(0, i * coef));

            // Bit-reversed addressing permutation
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                int j = (int)((uint)ReverseBits(i) >> (32 - levels));
                if (j > i)
                {
                    Complex temp = vector[i];
                    vector[i] = vector[j];
                    vector[j] = temp;
                }
            }

            // Cooley-Tukey decimation-in-time radix-2 FFT
            for (int size = 2; size <= n; size *= 2)
            {
                int halfsize = size / 2;
                int tablestep = n / size;
                for (int i = 0; i < n; i += size)
                {
                    for (int j = i, k = 0; j < i + halfsize; j++, k += tablestep)
                    {
                        Complex temp = vector[j + halfsize] * expTable[k];
                        vector[j + halfsize] = vector[j] - temp;
                        vector[j] += temp;
                    }
                }
                if (size == n)  // Prevent overflow in 'size *= 2'
                    break;
            }
        }
```

And here Bluestein.

```
            public static void TransformBluestein(Complex[] vector, bool inverse)
        {
            // Find a power-of-2 convolution length m such that m >= n * 2 + 1
            int n = vector.Length;
            if (n >= 0x20000000)
                throw new ArgumentException("Array too large");
            int m = 1;
            while (m < n * 2 + 1)
                m *= 2;

            // Trignometric table
            Complex[] expTable = new Complex[n];
            double coef = Math.PI / n * (inverse ? 1 : -1);
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                int j = (int)((long)i * i % (n * 2));  // This is more accurate than j = i * i
                expTable[i] = Complex.Exp(new Complex(0, j * coef));
            }

            // Temporary vectors and preprocessing
            Complex[] avector = new Complex[m];
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                avector[i] = vector[i] * expTable[i];
            Complex[] bvector = new Complex[m];
            bvector[0] = expTable[0];
            for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
                bvector[i] = bvector[m - i] = Complex.Conjugate(expTable[i]);

            // Convolution
            Complex[] cvector = new Complex[m];
            Convolve(avector, bvector, cvector);

            // Postprocessing
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                vector[i] = cvector[i] * expTable[i];
        }


        /* 
         * Computes the circular convolution of the given complex vectors. Each vector's length must be the same.
         */
        public static void Convolve(Complex[] xvector, Complex[] yvector, Complex[] outvector)
        {
            int n = xvector.Length;
            if (n != yvector.Length || n != outvector.Length)
                throw new ArgumentException("Mismatched lengths");
            xvector = (Complex[])xvector.Clone();
            yvector = (Complex[])yvector.Clone();
            Transform(xvector, false);
            Transform(yvector, false);
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                xvector[i] *= yvector[i];
            Transform(xvector, true);
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)  // Scaling (because this FFT implementation omits it)
                outvector[i] = xvector[i] / n;
        }

        private static int ReverseBits(int val)
        {
            int result = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++, val >>= 1)
                result = (result << 1) | (val & 1);
            return result;
        }
```

And this is the input per periode with an interval of 0,00001953125.

```
0
 0.03141
 0.06279
 0.09411
 0.12533
 0.15643
0.18738
 0.21814
 0.24869
 0.27899
 0.30902
 0.33874
 0.36812
 0.39715
 0.42578
 0.45399
 0.48175
 0.50904
 0.53583
0.56208
 0.58779
 0.61291
 0.63742
 0.66131
 0.68455
0.70711
 0.72897
 0.75011
 0.77051
 0.79016
 0.80902
 0.82708
 0.84433
 0.86074
 0.87631
 0.89101
 0.90483
 0.91775
 0.92978
 0.94088
 0.95106
 0.96029
 0.96858
 0.97592
0.98229
 0.98769
 0.99211
 0.99556
 0.99803
 0.99951
1
 0.99951
   0.99803
   0.99556
   0.99211
   0.98769
   0.98229
   0.97592
   0.96858
   0.96029
   0.95106
   0.94088
   0.92978
  0.91775
   0.90483
   0.89101
   0.87631
   0.86074
   0.84433
  0.82708
  0.80902
  0.79016
   0.77051
   0.75011
   0.72897
   0.70711
   0.68455
   0.66131
   0.63742
   0.61291
   0.58779
   0.56208
   0.53583
   0.50904
   0.48175
   0.45399
   0.42578
   0.39715
  0.36812
   0.33874
   0.30902
   0.27899
   0.24869
   0.21814
  0.18738
   0.15643
   0.12533
   0.09411
   0.06279
   0.03141
   0
   -0.03141
   -0.06279
   -0.09411
   -0.12533
   -0.15643
   -0.18738
  -0.21814
   -0.24869
   -0.27899
   -0.30902
   -0.33874
   -0.36812
-0.39715
   -0.42578
   -0.45399
   -0.48175
   -0.50904
   -0.53583
  -0.56208
   -0.58779
   -0.61291
   -0.63742
   -0.66131
   -0.68455
   -0.70711
   -0.72897
   -0.75011
   -0.77051
   -0.79016
   -0.80902
   -0.82708
  -0.84433
   -0.86074
   -0.87631
   -0.89101
   -0.90483
   -0.91775
  -0.92978
   -0.94088
   -0.95106
   -0.96029
   -0.96858
   -0.97592
   -0.98229
   -0.98769
   -0.99211
   -0.99556
   -0.99803
   -0.99951
   -1
  -0.99951
   -0.99803
   -0.99556
   -0.99211
   -0.98769
   -0.98229
  -0.97592
   -0.96858
   -0.96029
   -0.95106
   -0.94088
   -0.92978
  -0.91775
   -0.90483
   -0.89101
   -0.87631
   -0.86074
   -0.84433
   -0.82708
   -0.80902
   -0.79016
   -0.77051
   -0.75011
   -0.72897
   -0.70711
  -0.68455
   -0.66131
   -0.63742
   -0.61291
   -0.58779
   -0.56208
  -0.53583
   -0.50904
   -0.48175
   -0.45399
   -0.42578
   -0.39715
   -0.36812
   -0.33874
   -0.30902
   -0.27899
   -0.24869
   -0.21814
   -0.18738
   -0.15643
   -0.12533
   -0.09411
   -0.06279
   -0.03141
   0
```

I have no idear what this peak could be. The only thing i can say is, when my interval is bigger the peak at the beginning is also bigger:
Interval [0,00001953125](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vL7Aj.jpg) ; [0,0001953125](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ry648.jpg) ; [0,001953125](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iax5V.jpg)

Here is how i create the input of the fft. Just my shown input and the intervall....

```
                    float UsedInterval = float.Parse(Interval.Replace(",", "."), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                float x = 0; //Intervall starting at 0
                foreach (var line in input)
                {
                    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line)) continue; //delete empty lines

                    x += UsedInterval;  //add intervall
                    double y = double.Parse(line.Replace(",", "."), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

                    arr.Add(new Vector2XY(x, y));
                }
```

I hope you can help me with my problems and thanks for your attention.

When I do a 256bit ZeroPadding FFT with the upper Data over one periode and the interval 0,00001953125 [this is my ouput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7PlWh.jpg)

Comment: It's probably just the "smeared" DC component - the smearing is due to [spectral leakage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_leakage) because you are presumably not applying a [window function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function).

Comment: Could you show code for generation input data?

Comment: i added how i generate the input data

Comment: Emm.. So `Complex` structure contains x-coordinate (sloped line) as real part and some data as imaginary part??

Comment: sry, but what do you mean with "sloped line" ? the complex structure contains in x  the consecutive interval(newinterval[i] = lastinterval + interval) as real part  and in Y as imaginary part the amplitude of the sinus wave in y-Coordinates

Comment: @PaulR would a window function not change my complete output? the problem i have is, that the output I want and I get is identical. only the first peak is there for no reason.

Comment: Well I haven't look at what you are doing in detail, but iff you are certain your input signal has 0 mean, then you should not be seeing a large magnitude value in bin 0. If you are then it may be that you still have a bug in your implementation or the calling code. If you have MATLAB (or a free equivalent such as Octave) then I would suggest using that to get a correct result to use for validation.

Comment: Incidentally, when I run your input data above through Octave (using a 256 point zero-padded FFT) I get a large peak at bin 1 (i.e. the second bin) and a small peak around bin 6 - 7, which seems to be completely different to what you are seeing.

Comment: @PaulR I edited a picture of my output, when i use the exact input I posted with a 256 bit ZeroPadding FFT, does your output look mich different, sounds like i only have a different X-axis for me.

Comment: Yes, that's pretty much the same shape that I see in Octave - large peak in bin 1. My first few magnitude values are: `0.00000 103.64588 43.32311 12.50027 2.78130 1.29758 2.52833 2.19687 1.18639 0.12931 0.59205 0.84125 0.68176 0.29628 0.10578 0.36503 0.41533 0.28466 0.06416 ...` (note: may be a scaling factor of 256 difference between these values and yours).

Comment: my values are: 0.396503; 103.54556940286905; 43.401555598543986; 12.548446816875108, 2.7987028409821852; 1.3053979152802555; 2.5495366839185123.... so pretty much the same.
When i change the interval to 0,1 I get again this high peak at 0.... then my values are: 2030.1019753441215; 941.1632490780072; 476.50242369757035; 273.19420359885532 ; 198.29127537896227; 167.22125916978285 ; 143.55100789080504; 120.02590579990266

Comment: @PaulR  ... in my plot the value is divided by N/2 ... but in  my upper post i wrote the raw output

Answer (score 1):

You should fill real part of complex input with `Sin(coeff*i)` and imaginary part with zero  - pure real input, and you'll get right output without large peak near zero - it is due to linear component of current real part.

Comment: I tried it, and it was pretty close to the solution. I had to put the real Part to Zero and now the ouput is correct.